# Contour extraction from raster does not finish in Qgis. How to find out if a raster is damaged

Tags: qgis, raster, contour

Execution of "extraction" - "contours" in Qgis is impossible.
The process never finishes, I stopped it after 35 min.

The contour extraction works for all other raster files. 
I have tried with copies and converted the format but nothing works.

I can find the contour folder and the shapefile of the created contour but when imported to Qgis they don't show anything.

Is there a way to find out if the raster is damaged, or what cause there might be to this problem?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the raster?

Comment: @Hasan Mustafa http://www.filedropper.com/dem15-depth1

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your raster has some very odd low values associated with it:

[image]

These values are clearly not related to the rest of the data and they fall along the very edges of the dataset.  Not even setting the lower value to 0 or copying the lower value into the additional No Data value seemed to work.  It is almost certainly this that is causing the contour tool to fall over.

I managed to successfully contour the dataset by using raster calculator to eliminate values over 0 (you could set this to whatever you wanted) and then run the contour on this raster.

To do this:

Open the Raster Calculator and enter the code:

```
(Raster Name > 0) * Raster Name
```

This selects all raster pixels of value > 0 and sets their value to 1; then it multiplies this value of 1 by the original value of the raster.  Values of <= 0 are set to zero and end up as zero in the final calculation.

Run the contour on the new raster that is created by the calculator - 5m contours calculated below:

[image]